# AngularJS - a way to timeout html input for a second and then call $watch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For example: I am typing in input text, that has an ng-model, and the $watch gets called instantly. Is there a way to call $watch after, let's say 2sec have passed from the last key pressed on the input control?

Comment: What you need is some form of `debounce`. Here's the lodash implementation: http://lodash.com/docs#debounce You'll find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986895/jquery-ajax-search-debounce

Comment: I have tried with debounce from Underscore.js, it works, thx. Gonna also check the directive for the long run. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple directive for this kind of tasks. Consider this code:

```
.directive('delayedModel', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=delayedModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.val(scope.model);

            scope.$watch('model', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    element.val(scope.model);        
                }
            });

            var timeout;
            element.on('keyup paste search', function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    scope.model = element[0].value;
                    element.val(scope.model);
                    scope.$apply();
                }, attrs.delay || 500);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" delayed-model="searchText" data-delay="500" />
```

So the only thing you need to change is you use `delayed-model` instead of `ng-model`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NuKE5Jt1aFY1RJsO71Jw?p=preview