# How to prevent $.POST if content hasn't changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, user-interface

I make a `$.post` call by sending array of objects (selected values from a checkbox tree) to my `API` **every time the mouse leave the div where checkbox tree is located**. The issue is that the user by moving randomly the mouse could leave and enter the div houndreds of times so that will cause useless `$.post` submission without getting new data as the sent content hasn't changed.

Actually here is how the code looks like right now:

```
$("div.sidebar-wrapper")
    .mouseleave(function () {
        postPareto();
    });

function postPareto() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(config_Array()),
        url: "api/prodotti/pareto/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (dati) {
            tablePareto(dati);
        }
    });
}
```

So my question is, is there a way to prevent the `$.post` to being submissed if the content hasn't changed or should i just find another approach to submiss the checkbox selection (as it's a checkbox tree i chose to submit data on mouseleave so the user will have some time to decide what to check)?

Comment: There is no native way to achieve this. You could, however, simply check before your `$.post`, if the data has changed by comparing the serialized data.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948383/how-to-implement-debounce-fn-into-jquery-keyup-event you could use a debounced function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery ajax search debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986895/jquery-ajax-search-debounce)

Comment: And maybe this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987233/5900163

Comment: @Keff so i should use debounced on change of chebox instead of calling the ajax on mouse leave?

Comment: It depends, is the checkbox the only data that changes? or do you have more fields? Could you post your html as well? it might help me better understand the issue.

Comment: @Keff actually it's a checkbox tree generated dynamically from json that look's like this https://imgur.com/2Nchn1I so se user can choose of which 'store' see the data but obviously it's a bad practise to show new data after each checkbox has been checked as he would check more than one 'store' of which see the data

Comment: Okey, I understand, I'm going to post a solution, maybe it will be enough for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would do the following (simple solution):

```js
$("div.sidebar-wrapper")
    .mouseleave(function () {
        postPareto();
    });

// Save reference to previous value
let prevValue = null;
function postPareto() {
    let data = JSON.stringify(config_Array());

    // If it is the same value we can return and not perform POST 
    if (data === prevValue){
        return;
    } else {
        // Assign new value to prevValue
        prevValue = data;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(config_Array()),
        url: "api/prodotti/pareto/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (dati) {
            tablePareto(dati);
        }
    });
}
```

It might be a good idea to look into rxjs, it's quite cool and powerful for reactive sites. For example in rxjs you could do:

```
const input = document.querySelector('div.sidebar-wrapper');
const observable = fromEvent(input, 'mouseleave');

observable
  .map((event: any) => config_Array()),
  .distinctUntilChanged() // Returns an Observable that emits all items emitted by the source Observable that are distinct by comparison from the previous item.
  .subscribe((resp) => {
    // This will only be called if value changes
    console.log(resp); // resp will be the result from `config_Array()`
  });
```

You can check [this](https://medium.com/@kavisha.talsania/rxjs-debouncetime-and-distinctuntilchanged-c9f11db4d45f) article, which explains this a bit more in depth

Comment: awesome i tought by saving the previous data and by comparing it was going to decrease the performance of the website but i was wrong. thank you..

Comment: A pleasure, It might decrease a little bit, but I doubt it decreases it so much to need to worry about it...